# Duplicate values in the <select> tag after update session

Tags: java, jsp, session, jstl

Spread a piece of code of my jstl tag `<forEach>` on jsp page:

```
<select>    
    <c:if test="${!empty codeofcountries}">
      <c:forEach var="codecoun" items="${codeofcountries}">
            <option value="${codecoun.kods}">${codecoun}</option>
      </c:forEach>
  </c:if>
</select>
```

My controller:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType(request.getResponseContentType());
        PPUZ_NDI_MNS_ENEEPortletSessionBean sessionBean = getSessionBean(request);
        if( sessionBean==null ) {
            response.getWriter().println("<b>NO PORTLET SESSION YET</b>");
            return;
        }
        sessionBean.setDefaultInfoText();

        String jsp = Start_JSP;
        switch (sessionBean.getMode()) {
            case Start:
                jsp = Start_JSP;
                break;
            case Main:
                jsp = Main_JSP;
                break;
            case Creat:
            case Edit:
            case Copy:
                jsp = CreatEdit_JSP;
        }
        request.setAttribute("codeofcountries", sessionBean.getKodNameList());
        PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(getJspFilePath(request, jsp));
        rd.include(request, response);
```

When I go to portlet all handled well, the list is generated from the array and displayed in the tag `<select>` as I need. But when I reran the session on the portal, the value of the tag (select) is duplicated on jsp page. Do not leave the previous value in tag (select) and adds to it again the same list.

Comment: <c:if> my i know what this if does ?

Comment: condition of iterator

Comment: What is the code for `sessionBean.getKodNameList()`?

Comment: I have two variables through the query with SQL, I form them in KodNameList and transmits them to the tag <select> in JSP through key {codeofcountries}

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems the values are getting added into the list referenced by `sessionBean.getKodNameList()`, resulting in duplicate values.

To prevent this, I would advice to debug the code and check from where the values are getting added. However, for quick fix, you can either use [unmodifiableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) or Set (with `equals` and `hashCode` methods implemented in the respective class of course) for `KodNameList`.

Comment: I think my problem hide in my controller, in particular  request.setAttribute("codeofcountries", sessionBean.getKodNameList());

Answer (score 0):

Your variable in codeofcountries is getting all of getKodNameList() variables and your iterating over all of them and putting that into the select options.

So make sure your only putting what you want to access into the setAttribute variable

```
request.setAttribute("codeofcountries", sessionBean.getKodNameList());
```

Also I think you want to show the same thing as the value and not the whole array as below

```
<c:forEach var="codecoun" items="${codeofcountries}">
  <option value="${codecoun.kods}">${codecoun.kods}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I have two variables through the query with SQL, I form them in KodNameList and transmits them to the tag <select> in JSP through key {codeofcountries} .

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. But I would suggest setting the getKodNameList to a List variable and then you can access it from jsp. Example found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36161770/4307449

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to solving their problems in the class where I list is formed, the method and the class turned out to be static. In fact, it was possible to solve the problem in several ways, I settled on this one. Thank you for your attention!